# FileSystemWatcher blacklist?

Tags: c#, windows, file-io

The FileSystemWatcher class here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx

Has a filter property to let you specify what files you want to monitor (like a whitelist). Is there a way to specify what files you dont want to monitor? (like a blacklist)

I currently have a wrapper for the FileSystemWatcher class that traps each event and compares it with a list of paths to ignore but it doesn't work perfectly and I though that before spending a long time debugging it, I would ask if there is a built in way to do that.

Comment: What part doesn't work? Can you provide some examples and what is actually happening? There is no way to specify a blacklist per-se. What's also not clear is if the "path" are all sub folders of the folder you're listen to or are you listening to multiple folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no "blacklist" feature for `FileSystemWatcher`.

Comment: :( thats too bad, it would make life so much easier for me right now.